# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 256, 256]

Tags: python, numpy, keras, opencv, conv-neural-network

Everything is okay until I convert my image to grayscale. So the rgb's shape is `(256, 256, 3)` but grayscale has `(256, 256)`. When I feed it, I get that error.

```py
network = Sequential()

network.add(Convolution2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),strides=1,activation='relu',input_shape=(256, 256)))
network.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

# network.add(Convolution2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, activation='relu'))
# network.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))


network.add(Convolution2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, activation='relu'))
network.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

# network.add(Convolution2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, activation='relu'))
# network.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))


network.add(Convolution2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, activation='relu'))
network.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

# network.add(Convolution2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, activation='relu'))
# network.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))


network.add(Flatten())
network.add(Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))
network.add(Dense(2, activation = 'softmax'))

checkpoint_path = os.path.join("/---------/grayscale", "weights.best.hdf5")
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_path, monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=10)
callbacks_list = [checkpoint, es]

network.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to feed images of shape 256x256x1 in your network.

To convert your initial `x_train` into your new `X_train`:

```
X_train=np.reshape(x_train,(x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1],x_train.shape[2],1))
```

and finally change your input_shape from `input_shape=(256,256)` to `input_shape=(256,256,1)`

Comment: tnx. but why should I change it back to `(256, 256, 3)`?

Comment: it's `(256,256,1)`, sorry it was a mistake (edited)